# PWA listen for event upon receiving push notification (while app is not running)

Tags: firebase, vue.js, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to get the data that i receive from my push notification and display it in the pwa. The idea is that i have a push notification coming in with a text body, then the user clicks on the push notification and the PWA opens up with the data from the push notification displayed on the section. I have managed to get it work when it is open as i placed it in the mounted lifecycle and the function activates when it listens to the message that comes in. The only problem is when the push notification comes in, the user will not be having the PWA all the way. So how do i overcome this? I have tried inserting in other lifecycle methods but it seems redundant since the PWA is not even opened yet when the push notification arrives. Hope anyone here can advise on this. Thank you very much.

```
mounted(){
      navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', (e) => {
        console.log('Push Notification received');
        console.log(e.data.firebaseMessagingData.notification.body);
        var timestamp = new Date().toLocaleTimeString(undefined, {hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit'});
        const robotMessage = {
          text: e.data.firebaseMessagingData.notification.body,
          isRobot: true,
          timestamp: timestamp
        }
        firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection("users")
        .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
        .collection("messages")
        .add({
          robotMessage: robotMessage.text,
          timestamp: robotMessage.timestamp
        });

        this.messages.push(robotMessage);
      });
    }
```

Comment: you listen for push notifications in the service worker. I think you are trying in the UI code.

Comment: As you said, the notification will not showing in the PWA, that indicated that the notification may have some issue.  the noticification should be allow [web push](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#customizing-a-message-across-platforms).

Comment: @ShawnDiWu notification is showing well. I just want to transfer the body text in the notification onto the UI when i click on the notification and it opens up the pwa

Comment: you have to [retrieve an instance of Firebase Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive), for more specific you have to retrieve the message 'e', so that it can handle background.

Comment: yup i wrote my code with reference to it. The only problem is that i am only able to retrieve the msg e when i listen for the "msg" or notification coming when i have the pwa open (since the listener is in the mounted cycle). I'm trying to retrieve the e without having the PWA open so technically when notification comes in, i will be able to click on it and retrieve the e payload and display it on my UI.

Comment: I thought of storing the payload when i got on background msg but i found out other firebase libraries are not available in sw so storing it in firestore and retrieving it when the PWA opens under the created lifecycle is not possible. Would be open to hear if you know of a workaround for this. Thank you.

Comment: since the msg has been push in and with PWA, I guess the idea could be  retrieve the specific msg from the DB directly, is that you looking for?